# MySQL Backup default command in MySQL Administrator

Tags: mysql

I am writing a batch file to backup MySQL database. When I typed **mysqldump --help** in the command-line, it shows a long list of options. I want to know what are the default parameters that MySQL Administrator uses to create a full backup.

I am using Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqldump -u [username] -p [password] [databasename] > [backupfile.sql]`

[username] - this is your database username

[password] - this is the password for your database

databasename] - the name of your database

[backupfile.sql] - the file to which the backup should be written

Example:
 `mysqldump -u root -pasd dbname > dbbackup.sql`

Answer (score 1):

Note that the above solution would not backup stored procedures nor triggers, if the underlying database has any. A better command would be:

```
mysqldump -uroot -ppassword --routines --triggers dbname > dbbackup.sql
```

If there are no stored procedures nor triggers, the additional switches will do no harm